# How to pass the address of pointer into the argument of C API in Swift?

Tags: swift, xcode

I'm importing C API into Xcode with Swift5 language. I have trouble to pass the address of pointer into the argument:
Here's the prototype of C API:

`DEV_STATUS OpenDevice (PVOID * pHandle);`

What variable should I declare for this input argument?
I tried to declare below variable in swift:

```
var ppDevHandle: UnsafeMutablePointer<PVOID?>?
devStatus = OpenDevice(ppDevHandle)
```

It can be built but 'ppDevHandle' is nil before "OpenDevice" is called. And the API returned "invalid parameter".

Comment: Please provide typedef definitions of `PVOID` and `DEV_STATUS`. Also the Swift signature of the C-imported function.

Comment: Thanks Kamil, the definition of PVOID is `typedef void  *PVOID;`. Below answer works for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are either looking for this:

```swift
var ppDevHandle = PVOID()
devStatus = OpenDevice(&ppDevHandle)
```

Or this:

```swift
var ppDevHandle: PVOID?
devStatus = OpenDevice(&ppDevHandle)
```

Comment: Thanks herzi. The second one works for me. I got error message "Cannot invoke initializer for type 'PVOID' with no arguments" for the first one.

Comment: This usually depends on whether or not the handle argument is designed to be an opaque pointer in the C API. I'm happy this works for you now.Good luck with the rest of your project!